# Simulate wireless Lans in GNS3

Tags: gns3

Is it possible to run Wireless LAN Controllers (WLC) and Access Points (APs) on the GNS3?

There is no material or image APs in gns3? to emulate WLC, wifi AP etc.
I have Cisco vWLC 8.3.150.0 but I do not have Lightweight Access Points.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, there are images to emulate WLCs in GNS3. You can search for them on different websites or YouTube videos. For APs emulating, I don't think you'll find what you're looking for! Just if you have a real AP, you can connect it to your lab using a cloud...